# WSO2 Identity Server: SAML SSO Redirect URI is being converted to IP address of hostname

Tags: facebook, saml-2.0, wso2-identity-server

I have configured the travelocity app to work running on a localhost with the Identity Server running on the local host. Works well

Then I rebuild the travelocity app to work with an external IS - changing the travelocity.properties
SAML2.IdPURL 
OAuth2.TokenURL
OpenId.ProviderURL
to point to a public IS with valid SSL Certs

When I supplied https://www.mydomainname.com/commonauth in the Facebook "Valid OAuth redirect URIs" - the travelocity throws up an error "URL Blocked: This redirect failed because the redirect URI is not whitelisted in the app’s Client OAuth Settings. Make sure Client and Web OAuth Login are on and add all your app domains as Valid OAuth Redirect URIs." 
with the redirect contain the IP Address of the server rather than the domain name of the server

When I supply the IP address for commonauth, it fails with "SAML2 Response Issuer verification failed " - I am assuming it is because the ssl certs doesn't match the ipaddress.

So why and where is the redirect-uri being converted to IP-Address? 
And mainly how can I resolve this?

Comment: You need to change the SAML2.IdPEntityId property in the travelocity.properties to match the value of the Residentity IDp --> SAML issuer value

Comment: I changed SAML2.IdPEntityId to the "public-name-Identity-Server" - but I still get "URL Blocked: This redirect failed because the redirect URI is not whitelisted .....".. I ensured that Valid OAuth redirect URIs in my Facebook has the correct redirect URL. So I  ran some SSO tracer - and it seems samlp:AuthnRequest to the IdentityServer returns with a 302 - and the 302 contains the www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?scope=email&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2F**ipaddress**%2Fcommonauth& ... the ipaddress is being send back by the Identity Server - IS should send back the server name

Comment: seems like the problem is in the IP address to hostname mapping rather than an IS specific problem.

Comment: @farasath - your solution is right. The reason that was not working was I had rebuild the IS from another disk snapshot on google cloud engine - and the database had traces of the old ip address. If you post your comment as an answer I am happy to accept it.

Comment: awesome :) . Will post as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the SAML2.IdPEntityId property in the travelocity.properties to match the value of the

Residentity IDP --> Inbound Authentication Configs --> SAML --> SAML issuer value.

After you configure your IS with a hostname.

Answer (score 0):

You can verify the steps you followed with the steps in blog [[1](https://pulasthiharasgama.wordpress.com/2016/02/08/federated-authentication-between-two-identity-servers/)].

Comment: I have travelocity on my localhost and Identity Server as external. I am not sure the steps in the mentioned blog is relevant for my question